# Is Angular2 limited to a single root element in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angular

In Angular1, let's say I have a template for `my-directive` like this:

```
<li>First element</li>
<li>Second element</li>
<li>Third element</li>
```

Let's say I want to use this directive like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Some unique content</li>
    <my-directive /> <!-- placeholder for the li elements I re-use -->
</ul>
```

When rendering with option `replace: false` I get the following:

```
<ul>
    <li>Some unique content</li>
    <my-directive> <!-- Nested li elements here are a problem -->
        <li>First element</li>
        <li>Second element</li>
        <li>Third element</li>
    </my-directive>
</ul>
```

This isn't great, because I just want to add the `li` elements to a list whenever I insert the directive.

When `replace: true` I get the error: `Template for directive 'myDirective' must have exactly one root element.`

I understand why the directive requires a single root element, but will Angular2 have this limitation as well?

Comment: I have no idea what this question is about. Can you please explain what you try to accomplish (concrete example) if possible and what you think is not possible the way you want it?

Comment: Hehe, sorry... Question just kind of popped into my head.  Is this any better?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you question is about.

Comment: *"inconvenient for CSS"* ... example of problem would help

Comment: In angular2 there is a shadow DOM and view encapsulation, where CSS cannot bleed into other components. With this feature, it shouldn't matter if there is a root element or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular the template is added to the tag where the selector matches and the template can have an arbitrary number of children.

If you don't want to the component selector to be equal the tag name you can use an attribute selector

```
@Component({selector: '[my-component]' ...
```

```
<div my-component></div>
```

Comment: Hi Günter, will Angular place the component's content inside the <div my-component> element? Is there a way to make Angular2 replace a content tag?

Comment: So will the template be rendered inside the <ng-content> tag, or does it replace it? Because in Angular1, if a directive has `replace: true` then it is only allowed one root element.

Comment: My previous comment is misleading because I didn't re-read your question properly before I posted it (deleted). I think the problem you'll run into with approach is that it will result in `<li>  <li>First ...</li>  <li>Second ...</li>   <li>Third ...</li>  </li>`. Angular 2 also can only have one root element, that's the element you add to the dom `<li my-component></li>` is the root element and the template will be added inside it (as children).

Comment: Hi Günter, I think that answers my question. So if I understand you correctly, Angular2 also always requires a single element to insert templates into, and that element is also what the controller gets attached to.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested it and you are able to have more than just one root element

```
    @Component({
        selector: 'multiple-roots',
        template: `
            <div>
                First Root
            </div>
            <div>
                Second Root
            </div>
            <div>
                Third Root
            </div>
        `,
    })
```

For example, if you inject the component and call it on an html template

```
<multiple-roots></multiple-roots>
```

It would render as:

```
<mutliple-roots>
   <div>
       First Root
   </div>
   <div>
       Second Root
   </div>
   <div>
       Third Root
   </div>
</mutliple-roots>
```

For a better reference please check out the [Angular2's Tutorial Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5c0efA0dSXkWxdlHrWal?p=preview)

Comment: Hi Gabu, almost - what I want to know is: does Angular render those three divs inside the <multiple-roots> element? Or does it replace the <multiple-roots> element as if it was a placeholder?